# ASP.NET C# Datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to save date through textbox to a SQL Server database using parameters as below:

```
SqlParameter p15 = new SqlParameter
{   
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
    ParameterName = "prj_start_date",
    SqlValue = txtStartDate.Text
};
```

and the following error appear:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '12-12-2015' to data type int.

I have try use casting using convert but this was not worked

In addition `textmode= date` doesn't work in IE

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use debug, search in google how to use debug in C#! You are trying to convert 12-12-2015 to int somewhere, because of that you have this problem.

Comment: May be try 2015-12-12 once.

Comment: Thank u Appreciate you efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you use a jQuery DatePicker rather than using a user input which would save you from invalid inputs from end users.

You are getting this error because you are passing a String type to a Date Type.

Try this:

```
string enteredDate = txtStartDate.Text.Trim();
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(enteredDate, InvariantCulture);

SqlParameter p15 = new SqlParameter
{
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
    ParameterName = "prj_start_date",
    SqlValue = date;
};
```

Comment: But how if i want to leave the textbox of date is null ??

Comment: You can check while passing SqlParameter if textbox value is empty.
`if(String.IsNullorEmpty(txtStartDate.Text.Trim()))
        {
            SqlDateTime s = SqlDateTime.Null;
        }`
And pass s as value to your Sqlparameter

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered parsing the text into a `DateTime` object in C# - `ParseExact` allows you to give a specific format string. Then you do not have to deal with Text on the SQL level, particularly given that your date form is non-ISO-standard and open to cultural interpretation.

Comment: Thank U :) Appreciate you efforts.